# Fuse sshfs and java file Write fails

Tags: java, java-io, fuse, sshfs

I have two VPS on a farm and I whant to connect them with sshfs, to share some directories on a java application.

```
Source                  Destination
-------------------------------------------
VPS1:/app/path/data --> VPS2:/app/path/data
```

VPS 2 read and write in the sshfs mount and via shell scripts this does work regularly and very fast, because of the gigabit ethernet connection.

When my application starts to write files on VPS 2, in a non-predictable way fails to write files.

I tried to unmount location and write files locally and it works fine, without exception.

There are some strange incopatibilities between java.io.FileWriter and fuse? Or I simply miss something on mounting fs?

I tried this mount options:

```
sshfs user@VPS1_IP:/app/path/data /app/path/data 
      -o rw,allow_other,uid=${uid},gid=${gid}
```

An appending also:

```
reconnect,cache=no
```

The only **non-standard** thing I do with java is to write file, than rename it, to make an atomic operation, but when it fails nothing is written or renamed..

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a lot, Davide

Comment: And what exactly exception you get?

Comment: There are numerous issues with `File.renameTo()` on linux mounted directories and windows Shares if this what you use to copy. Apache commons-io `FileUtils` does not suffer from these problems

Comment: The strange thing is that no exception are thrown until file is read:
the steps are:
1. Check if file does not exists
2. If not exists, write file (no exceptions)
3. Read file
This is not a sync trouble, because file is no written until I try to do this operation again..

Comment: Thanks BGR, i can try apache commons io FileUtils and tells you about it..

Comment: I decided to take another approach: This thing was for cache reasons. I prefer to write cache files locally for some reasons: performance, skill (I have no idea on how to manage sshfs), take two applications separated and share as a service. I think it is a better way!